# How to target Debian stable but develop on testing?

Tags: linux, debian, cross-compiling, chroot, binary-compatibility

We have some C++ applications which are developed specifically and only for Debian stable (x86).

Currently, development of these application is also done using a Debian stable (x86) system so the developer has all the same library versions as on the target system.
Occasionally, I also need to work on these components and it keeps bugging me that I'm stuck with a very outdated version of KDevelop (4.0.1 vs. the latest 4.4.1). I'd like to use a more up-to-date system for development (like the latest Ubuntu or Debian testing) but how can I create binaries suitable for the target system?
Is there some simple way I can tell the compiler/linker to use the library versions which are available on the target platform only?
I looked at [Emdebian](http://www.emdebian.org/) and their cross-compiling packages but I don't think this would work for me. They seem to have only packages for targetting other architectures like ARM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using schroot.

```
$ sudo apt-get install schroot debootstrap

$ sudo debootstrap squeeze /opt/squeeze
```

Then in /etc/schroot/schroot.conf add and entry like this:

```
[squeeze]
type=directory
description=Debian squeeze
directory=/opt/squeeze
users=myusername
root-users=myusername
```

After that you are ready to install packages in the chroot:

```
$ schroot -c squeeze -u root
(squeeze)# aptitude
```

After you install all the packages you need, you can enter the chroot as a normal user (as long as you are listed in the schroot.conf file):

```
$ schroot -c squeeze
```

The schroot program is also useful for running newer X11 applications on older desktops, and you only need to pass the environment along as well:

```
$ schroot -c squeeze -p
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution for that would be to install a stable `chroot`-ed Debian distribution under e.g. a testing (or an instable) Debian distribution (or even some non-Debian but Debian "compatible" thing, like Mint or Ubuntu).

You want to use the [debootstrap](http://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap) utility (to install the chrooted distribution), and you'll need to [bind-mount](https://fermilinux.fnal.gov/documentation/tips/mount-bind-chroot) pseudofile systems like `/proc/`, `/dev/`, `/sys/` and perhaps your `/home`. Then use `schroot` to go into your stable Debian (and compile inside it).

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Install Debian testing on your workstation
2. Create a chroot jail.
3. Install Debian stable into chroot jail
4. Compile your project from within the jail.